# How to protect a WYSIWYG editor from XSS attacks?

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, textarea, xss, summernote

I am using the Summernote WYSIWYG-editor (as shown below) and found that it uses HTML tags to format text.

```
<textarea name="body" id="editor" value="{{old('body')}}" rows="10" required></textarea>
```

How to protect my application from XSS attacks? I store the input as plain text, and outputting in using : `{!! $body !!}`.

Is it possible to filter the `textarea` for vulnerable input, such as: `<script>alert("boom")</script>`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

By default, Laravel does not provide any mechanism to remove certain tags from a given input, thus you need to use a third-party package like [Purifier](https://github.com/mewebstudio/Purifier).

## Installing Purifier

As shown below, Purifier can simply be installed using `Composer`.

```
composer require mews/purifier
```

## Configuration

To customize Purifier's default settings, publish the configuration file (`config/purifier.php`).

```
php artisan vendor:publish --provider="Mews\Purifier\PurifierServiceProvider"
```

Now, navigate to `config/purifier.php` and adjust the `HTML.Allowed` entry as needed. Note that all tags that are not listed within this entry will be removed by the `clean()` method.

An exhaustive reference of configuration options can be found [here](http://htmlpurifier.org/live/configdoc/plain.html).

---

## Example

```
clean("<p>Good</p> <script>alert('Bad')</script>")
```

> Output: `<p>Good</p>`

Comment: I also use Purifier. It's a bit of a hassle to set it up but once done, WYSIWYG uploads are protected from XSS attack and all stuff you don't want in the upload of a contributor. @pvaitonis may have to experiment a bit with it's possibilities.

Comment: I don't find any example or documentation, how to allow some tags to use.